# set nginx default path and route

Tags: php, nginx

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
I have a  nginx  sevice,it has some projects,when I use this config,it can work well.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;


sendfile        on;



keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    root           html;
    ***location /v1/ {
        alias html/v1/;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }***
    location /v2/ {
        alias   html/v2/;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }
    location /mch/ {
        alias   html/mch/;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }
    location /user/ {
        alias   html/user/;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }
    location /merchant/ {
        alias   html/merchant/;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }


}





}
```

And then I want set the default path v1.I change the config like this:

```
location / {
        alias  html/v1/;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }
```

It worked wrong whit an error like this:

```
No input file specified.
```

Can someone  help me?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify which file you want to execute while hitting `localhost/v1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `No input file specified` message is caused by [Passing Uncontrolled Requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php).

If you want the URI `/` to access the `/v1/` path, perform a redirect:

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    location = / {
        return 302 /v1/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

In the above example, I have removed some location blocks that were not performing any function.